# UE4 - noob question abt workflow with mixamo

Tags: unreal-engine4, mixamo

I am not the best animator so I wanted to use mixamo in unreal engine to just let some people idle around.
I have tried importing those preset mixamo characters and it worked perfectly.

But when I try to do the exact same with characters I sculpted on zbrush and upload them on mixamo my unreal file just crashes and burns. Am I making some beginners mistake ??

My workflow really isnt that special.
its literally just

zbrush:
sculping the low poly (2k - that too much ??) version of my model and UVing it - export it as an obj -

mixamo:
mixamo autorig it - download the t-pose model - download the animation version -

unreal:
try to import the t- posed downloaded model - cry as unreal goes down in flames and takes my dreams with it

Am I being dumb ? Or is it just normal that I cannot just auto rig stuff I dont want to rig myself ? This some lazy-proof mechanism to make me do this the hard way ?

If thats the case would someone please tell me what their pipeline is for just letting a random character sit at a table and wiggle their feet in the background ?

I would be beyond grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I finally know what the problem was.
So if anyone else is struggling with the import of a skeletal mesh:
It needs to have a material assigned.

this was the error log:
Assertion failed: (Index >= 0) & (Index < ArrayNum) [File:D:\Build++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers/Array.h] [Line: 614] Array index out of bounds: 0 from an array of size 0

literally just including a material will fix it